# .Select not updatingObservableCollection of view model objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ObservableCollection` of type `FilterableListItem`(below) and I make the following query,

```
this.Gears.Select(r => r.IsAvailible = r.Value == "X6");
```

But it does not update any of the items in the list. How would I make the select statement update the list?

```
public class FilterableListItem : ViewModelBase
{
    private string value;

    private bool isAvailible;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public bool IsAvailible
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isAvailible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.isAvailible)
            {
                this.isAvailible = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Select` does not update anything, it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which you then need to assign back to your variable. Just use a `foreach` and update your objects accordingly.

Comment: Also another gotcha: only adds and deletes to the collection will trigger an update notification to the WPF layer (er, and edits too).

Comment: @code4life Yeah, I implemented the change suggested and I just noticed it was not updating, having to manually call OnPropertyChanged

Comment: That's what happens when you swap out the original collection with the new collection - the one that was derived from the `select` query. In those cases you just have to manually call the `INotifyPropertyChanged` yourself, no way to dodge that bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `Select` should not be used to update your objects, but to project each element in your collection.

You should infact be using a standard `foreach` to update your objects:

```
foreach (var item in Gears)
    item.IsAvailable = (r.Value == "X6");
```

This will update your items accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try use:

```
foreach (var r in this.Gears) r.IsAvailible = r.Value == "X6";
```

Answer (score 1):

.Select doesn't update the object but rather return an IEnumerable of modified objects. Try this:

```
this.Gears = new ObesrvableCollection<FilterableListItem>(this.Gears.Select(r => r.IsAvailible = r.Value == "X6"));
```